# akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger]

Tags: scala, akka, slf4j

I am working in a project with Scala and Akka. Two days ago, I can't launch the test because this error is thrown:

[WARN] [10/20/2016 15:47:32.743] [pool-1-thread-1] [EventStream(akka://default)] Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond within Timeout(5000 milliseconds) to InitializeLogger(bus)
error while starting up loggers
akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due to [akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]]

I am working in a team with 2 collegues and they don't have any problem with the same code (same branch).

Any idea about what is happening?

Thank you so much in advance.